# Embedded JavaScript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have embedded JavaScript in ASP.NET application:

```
function HelloFromEmbedded()
{
    window.alert('Hello from embedded resource.');
}
```

In AssemblyInfo.cs file:

```
[assembly: WebResource("JavaScript1.Scripts.EmbeddedJavaScript.js", "text/javascript", PerformSubstitution = true)]
```

This is my ASP.NET web page:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreRender(e);

    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("EmbeddedJS", ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(this.GetType(), "JavaScript1.Scripts.EmbeddedJavaScript.js"));
}
```

I'd like to use embedded JavaScript in onmouseover event of text box in ASP.NET web page:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onmouseover="HelloFromEmbedded();"></asp:TextBox>
```

But, it doesn't work. I can't see why.

Comment: can you paste the final output html that this generates?

Comment: I've solved the problem in this way:

string js = ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(typeof(JavaScript1.WebForm2), JavaScript1.Scripts.EmbeddedJavaScript.js");
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("EmbeddedJS", js);

Comment: @tesicg : Please post your comment as answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

I've solved the issue in this way:

```
string js = ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(typeof(JavaScript1.WebForm2), JavaScript1.Scripts.EmbeddedJavaScript.js");
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("EmbeddedJS", js);
```